# CTkLabel.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to run this code, but I am getting the error which should not be there as I didn't specify any master argument. Please solve it for me.

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk 

import torch
import numpy as np

import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import vlc 
import random


app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("600x600")
app.title("Drowsy Boi 4.0")
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

vidFrame = tk.Frame(height=480, width=600)
vidFrame.pack()
vid = ctk.CTkLabel(vidFrame)
vid.pack()

counter = 0 
counterLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text=counter,  height=40, width=120, text_font=("Arial", 20), text_color="white", fg_color="teal")
counterLabel.pack(pady=10)

def reset_counter(): 
    global counter
    counter = 0 
resetButton = ctk.CTkButton(text="Reset Counter", command=reset_counter, height=40, width=120, text_font=("Arial", 20), text_color="white", fg_color="teal")
```

error:

```
counterLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text=counter,  height=40, width=120, text_font=("Arial", 20), text_color="white", fg_color="teal")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: CTkLabel.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
```

I am expecting this to be running without error.
As there are no positional arguments named `master`, and if I am wrong, then please tell me what argument to be added and what could be the solution.

Comment: _"I am getting the error which should not be there as I didn't specify any master argument."_ - that's exactly what the error is telling you: you didn't specify a master but one is required.

Answer (score 2):

**Description:**
the widgets in your code you provided are missing the master argument which is an important argument. It defines to which frame or label the widget should appear in.

```
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master = app, text="CTkButton", command=button_event)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Solution:**

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk 

import torch
import numpy as np

import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import vlc 
import random


app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("600x600")
app.title("Drowsy Boi 4.0")
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

vidFrame = tk.Frame(height=480, width=600)
vidFrame.pack()
vid = ctk.CTkLabel(vidFrame)
vid.pack()

counter = 0 
counterLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master = app, text=counter,  height=40, width=120, text_font=("Arial", 20), text_color="white", fg_color="teal")
counterLabel.pack(pady=10)

def reset_counter(): 
    global counter
    counter = 0 
resetButton = ctk.CTkButton(master = app, text="Reset Counter", command=reset_counter, height=40, width=120, text_font=("Arial", 20), text_color="white", fg_color="teal")
```

**Usage:**

master is used to guide the widget in which frame or label to put the widget in since you just created the window and named it as app, putting `master = app` will make the widgets appear in the app window. If you create another frame inside of the app window and want to show the button inside of that frame you will similarly do `master = frame`.
Furthermore check out the documentation of customtkinter library and observe that in every example code of the widget theres an argument master.

[CTKButton | CustomTkinter](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/button)